# Creating django models in the right way

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have django models as follows :

```
class Type(models.Model):
    limit = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    default = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Subscription(models.Model):
    started = models.DateField()
    type = models.OneToOneField(Type)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type.name


class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    subscription = models.OneToOneField(Subscription, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Thus, member and subscription need to be `OneToOneField` relation, and subscription and type also `OneToOneField` relation.

But I want that member gets subscription of type `default=true`, if he creates a new account.

This is maybe not the question as it should be, but however, I would like to hear advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Are sure you want these to be one-to-ones? In particular, subscription/type seems like it should be a one-to-many (ForeignKey); a subscription is of a specific type, but many subscriptions can be of that same type, surely?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, you're right. The subscription and type can be connected with ForeignKey.

Comment: @Boky you might be interested in this: https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying/blob/master/annoying/fields.py#L37

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two options:

1. Attach some function to `Member` `post_save` signal, in function create appropriate instances if it was called with `created=True`:

   ```
   from django.db.models.signals import post_save
   from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

   @receiver(post_save, sender='myapp.Member')
   def create_default_subscription(sender, instance, created, raw, using, update_fields):
       if created:
           <here create your subscription>
   ```
2. Override `Member.save()` method and create appropriate instances if `self.pk` is `None`.

   ```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.pk is None:
           <here create your subscription>
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
   ```

In both cases, you need to remember to associate created `Subscription` with your new `Member`.